# delete query in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have these tables:

table1

```
id   type       name       parent    group_id
1    special    name1      0         21
2    Group      name2      1         19
3    Group      name3      1         22
4    special    name4      0         89
```

table2

```
id   version    mcs        user    right_id
1    0          15          27          3
2    0          15          27          4
```

where `right_id` in `table2` references `id` in `table1`

what I want is to delete the rows whose name name2 and name3 **without using joins**

I tried the following:

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE right_id in (19, 22);
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE name in ('name2','name3');
```

it works but what I want is to put name2 and name3 in variables and not use 19 and 22 directly.

Comment: Are you asking to delete the same rows from table2 that reference the rows form table1, without having to specify?  A bit confused on exactly what you're asking

Comment: why without joins?

Comment: I'm confused, that first delete shouldn't "work" since there are no rows in `table2` with those values in `right_id`. I don't see any apparent relation between the two tables.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery in the `in` operator in the first delete:

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE  right_id IN (SELECT id
                    FROM   table1
                    WHERE  name IN ('name2', 'name3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking to delete from table2 wherever you delete from table1, you want to use nested queries.

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE right_id IN (SELECT id
                                      FROM table1
                                      WHERE name IN ('name2', 'name3'))
```

EDIT: You could also use `join`

```
DELETE FROM table2 as t2, table1 as t1
WHERE t1.id = t2.right_id AND t1.name IN ('name2', 'name3')
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed and added join option

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small issue in the question,

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE right_id in (19, 22);
```

seems to be wrong. If you want to delete ones with the name2 and name3, that relates to the id 2 and 3. As right_id refers to the id, this should be,

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE right_id in (2, 3);
```

However to answer you, you can use a sub query without joins, like below

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE right_id in (SELECT id FROM table1 where name in ('name2','name3'));
```